# Finitely generated Dedekind domains

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain. Suppose that $R$ is finitely generated as a ring, say $R = \mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$ for some ideal $I \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.

<s>Is $R$ necessarily the ring of integers of a global field?</s>

Is the ring of fractions of $R$ necessarily a global field? What would be a good way to prove this?

Comment: What about $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ for a prime $p$?

Comment: @Mohan Did you mean $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(p,x)$ instead of $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(p)$ (as $\Bbb{F}_p(x)$ is a global field). There is also $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(xp-1)$, is it 'the ring of integers of $\Bbb{Q}$' ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I see now what goes wrong. I'll have to edit the question.

Comment: I gave a counter-example, $\Bbb{F}_p$ is not a global field.  Otherwise I'd say yes, if $char(R)=p$ then (Krull) $\dim(R)\le 1$ implies that $transcendenceDegree(Frac(R)/\Bbb{F}_p)\le 1$ so $Frac(R)$ is either a finite field or a finite extension of $\Bbb{F}_p(t)$. If $char(R)=0$ then $\dim(R)\le 1$ implies that $Frac(R)$ is a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: In the $\dim(R)=1$ case they are a localization of the integral closure of $\Bbb{F}_p[t]$ or $\Bbb{Z}$ (but for a function field there are many ways to embed $\Bbb{F}_p[t]$ and there is often no isomorphism between the integral closure of two different embeddings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof, with the help of the comments above. I tried to be as detailed as possible.

Typically, the definition of Dedekind domains includes fields. The fields that are finitely generated as rings are precisely the finite fields $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, and these are not global fields.

If additionally, $\mathrm{dim}(R)=1$, then there are two cases:

- $\mathrm{char}(R)=p$. Then $R$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra, so by the Noether Normalization Lemma there is an injective ring morphism $\mathbb{F}_p[t] \to R$ that turns $R$ into a finitely generated $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$-module. So $R$ is a finite $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$-extension, in particular it is integral. This implies that the fraction field $K$ of $R$ is generated by finitely many algebraic elements, as a field extension of $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$. So it is a finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, see [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09GH). So it is a global field.
- $\mathrm{char}(R)=0$. Because $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field, the standard Noether Normalization Lemma does not apply, but there is a more general version of Noether normalization in the notes by Hochster [here](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ehochster/615W10/supNoeth.pdf). It implies that $R[\tfrac{1}{n}]$ is finitely generated as $\mathbb{Z}[\tfrac{1}{n}]$-module, for some natural number $n$. Now the same proof applies as in characteristic $p$: since $R$ is integral and finitely generated, its fraction field will be generated as a field by finitely many algebraic elements. As a result, it is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. So it is a global field as well.